# Why does Stack Overflow have these restrictions for a newbie?

Tags: discussion

As a user, I see voting up/down answers that were helpful being a much lower barrier to engage with the community. I found myself wanting to vote up answers many times, but I got frustrated instead because I did not have enough points.

```
1) Should have minimum of 15 points to upvote an answer
2) Should have minimum of 20 points to add an attachment for a question
3) Should have minimum 120 points to downvote
```

Comment: If those barriers didn't exist, abuse of the system would be even simpler than it is now.

Comment: @Mahendra would you agree with my post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305491/stack-overflow-junior

Comment: @Craig It's giving 404 error(Page not found)

Answer (score 13):

These barriers to entry exist to force users to provide at least minimal proof that they understand how the system works and that the system can trust them. For example, imagine the 15 points barrier for upvoting didn't exist. Any random user could simply post some rubbish and create a number of sock puppet accounts to vote up his own answer, gaining more undeserved privileges in the process.

Reputation is tied to privileges, you need to earn those privileges by contributing positively to the community. That's SO's self-regulating mechanism.